# Stop a force reboot

Tags: updates, reboot, ota-update

Today I was prompted to install (firmware?) updates from ATT on my HTC Vivid. My phone is rooted and this apparently breaks the update process. The phone shut down and went to the red exclamation point / dead Android image.

The phone restarts normally and runs for ~30 seconds. It then gives me a "your phone will restart in 5 seconds" message and force shuts down.

Is there any way that I can stop the restart from happening automatically?

UPDATE: Problem solved. I cleared the cache. To do this I restarted the phone into the bootloader by pressing and holding the power button and down volume key. I then selected RECOVERY. From the next screen I selected wipe cache partition.

Comment: ClockworkMod recovery installed?

Comment: Yep. Used that to clear the cache and the problem went away. Lesson learned.

Comment: @BryanGlazer Feel free to answer your own question then (and accept your answer). This way your problem is shown solved even in lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I cleared the cache. To do this I restarted the phone into the bootloader by pressing and holding the power button and down volume key. I then selected RECOVERY. From the next screen I selected wipe cache partition.